# Separação de campos em array

Tags: php, csv

Possuo uma string que consiste em (aspas inclusas):

```
"campo","outrocampo","maisumcampo"
```

Preciso separar esses campos, sem as aspas, em um array.

O que estou fazendo é um

```
 $string = str_replace('"', NULL, $string)
```

e depois um

```
 $array = explode(',', $string);
```

Porém, se algum dos campos na string original vier a conter uma vírgula dentro da aspas, creio que terei problemas. Como evitar isso?

Comment: Evite títulos como "SOCORRO PRECISO DE AJUDA".

Comment: O melhor titulo de sempre no SOPT :D Depois apago o comentário, mas tinha de comentar.

Comment: @JorgeB. pelo menos ele foi sincero né :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que tal usar uma função que foi criada especificamente para ler CSV?

```
$array = str_getcsv($string);
```

Mais detalhes: [**Documentação**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: `fgetcsv($string)` também está certo, só que ele lê cada linha e daí interpreta como arquivo `csv`